# Azure CPU performance benchmark and/or specification

Tags: azure, cpu

I need to deploy a high performance number crunching service in Windows Azure. Are there any benchmarks out there about CPU performance in Azure?

I have found [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/windowsazurepurchasing/thread/d3ef3782-9087-4b7e-8b55-9983fab58181) mentioning it is a `AMD Opteron 2347 HE Quad-Core 1.9GHZ` but all [Windows Azure pages](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/faq/#) mention it is a 1.6 GHz CPU. There are no other specs anywhere to be found. The guy from the forum post mentioned he somehow run CPU-Z in an Azure WebRole. I wonder how that could be replicated to get some up-to-date results.

Comment: Why don't you run some benchmarking software on an Azure VM?

Comment: Sure. Can you tell me how exactly? I am open to suggestions.

Comment: As the answer suggests, you can just deploy a test project, and RDP on. Here are the results from my test on a small instance in North Europe data centre: http://coderead.wordpress.com/2011/11/29/cpu-z-on-an-azure-compute-instance/

Comment: Thanks! That's pretty much what I was after. You did it all for me so thanks again. And now I know how to do it myself if I ever need to do so again.

Comment: Amazon (and no doubt other providers) make much more powerful CPUs available in VMs than you can get from Azure, but for a higher cost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want to do is run CPU-Z then the simplest thing to do is to take one of the sample Azure web sites and when you deploy it make sure you've got remote desktop turned on.  Once it's deployed RDP into the instance, install and run any applications you like.  When you're done, delete the instance.

But there are a couple of things you'll need to keep in mind.  Just because the instance you deploy to has one type of CPU, that doesn't mean that the next one you deploy to will be the same.  While I'm sure MS got some bulk buying discounts on CPUs, Azure has been running long enough that some variation is bound to have crept in.  Also just because there is a multi core CPU installed, it doesn't mean you get access to all of it.  [Depending on the instance size](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/features/compute/) you get more of the CPU dedicated to your instance (in the case of an extra small instance you don't even get a whole core to yourself).

Comment: What you say makes perfect sense. And it is not that I am expecting to get an absolute CPU benchmark but just a sense of what is out there. If you see MS specs they reveal almost nothing. You basically haven't got a clue what you are dealing with. Still, I suppose CPUs should probably be relatively similar so that everybody gets similar performance. I assume only folks running "extra small instance" get to run on some old CPUs.

Comment: This site shows some system information about the azure instance it is running on: http://gacviewer.cloudapp.net/MachineDetails.aspx

Comment: link broken in the comment by knightpfhor